# Google Tag Manager causes lag in page loading

Tags: performance, google-tag-manager

There is a 5 second or so after the page is loaded, that e.g. clicking or hovering on elements won't work.

I figured out, it has to do with the Tag Manager.

Just like suggested in the guide, it's loading asynchronously.

Does somebody have any suggestion how to avoid this lag?

Comment: Largely depends on what is loaded in GTM. GTM by itself should not cause lags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was that was issue in our implementation, not in GTM.

Answer (score 1):

GTM shouldn't cause such delays - it loads asynchronously. If you want to test it - remove GTM from the website and check page load time. You can also use [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) and block GTM in the settings to prevent the script from running. Unless there are any custom HTML injections that prevent the buttons from working before all the content is loaded, it isn't GTM.

Looking at the load waterfall you should see which element blocks the page from loading.